# Issue with multiple shards and parent / child

Tags: elasticsearch, tire

I've nested documents, everything is fine in dev since I've only one shard, but in production it fails with the following message:

```
{"error"=>"RoutingMissingException[routing is required for [users]/[timeline_post]/[1]]", "status"=>500}
```

The logged query is:

```
curl -X POST "http://foo.qbox.io/users/timeline_post/1?parent=23" -d '{"id":1,"body":"foo"}'
```

I thought there were no need to specify routing if the parent is provided.

Any idea what's wrong here please?

FYI, I gave [other details here](https://github.com/karmi/retire/issues/883).

Comment: Was an issue from my Elastic Search provider, it fixed it after bug report

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My guess is you have routing.required=true set in your mappings. Setting a parent doc will only use the parent doc name for routing by default (note that it only uses the doc name and doesn't do any lookup of the shard the doc is on at all). When you're doing custom routing, you'll need to also include routing on documents with parents and also ensure yourself that each doc gets routed the same way as its parent.